# JavaFX 2.2 WebView

Tags: javafx-2

I am using Javafx and FXML . I have created my form . in one of my pages I have a Tree in the left pane (Split Pane) , and the right pain is a Webview inside the right Anchor pane.

when I select a node on the tree (treeItem) the webview will change accordingly to the respective site that was selected in the tree view.

This works (like a charm)when I run it as an application.

HOWEVER , when viewing this in the **browser**  (i.e. chrome , firefox and safari(mac)) i dont see the web view , it stays blank. i.e. the UI will load and the tree will be there , but the right jand pain never shows the embedded views.

When I run as a webstart I see the right views. The web pages that are embedded into the web views have a login, when i try login the web page flicker , like ther refresh and the login form is blanked, I have to enter the credential again.

not sure what is wrong or how to debug the browser / webstart side.

Answer (score 2):

> when viewing this in the browser (i.e. chrome , firefox and safari(mac)) i dont see the web view , it stays blank. i.e. the UI will load and the tree will be there , but the right jand pain never shows the embedded views.

If you not done so already, you will need to [sign your application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABJGFBH) to allow it to run outside of the [browser embedded Java application sandbox](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deploy_overview.htm#CEGJGHDA) so that the webview's network layer has permission to access the external locations.

Also monitor the webview loadworker's exception property to see if an exception or FAILED state was encountered:

```
Worker worker = webview.getEngine().getLoadWorker();
worker.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
  @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observableValue, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
    System.out.println("Browser state change: " + newState);
  }
});
worker.exceptionProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Throwable>() {
  @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Throwable> observableValue, Throwable oldThrowable, Throwable newThrowable) {
    System.out.println("Browser encountered a load exception: " + newThrowable);
  }
});
```

> not sure what is wrong or how to debug the browser / webstart side.

There is an excellent Oracle article on [debugging steps for webstart / browser embedded applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/plugin.html).  The article provides numerous pointers such as how to set debug and trace levels, etc.

Comment: thanks I will try this ... Light dawns on marble head... thanks guys i will revert

Comment: HI ... I have Managed to get my pages to run and display , HOWEVER the login of the embedded web pages still dont work ... i have SIGED the Jar files with netbeans IDE as well as trying javafxpackager

Comment: I have checked my java console : i get this (repeated)                      
network: Server http://www.indaba-analytics.com/auth/?destination=/t/Clientele/views/ClienteleLookupReports/ContactDataLookup?:embed=y requesting to set-cookie with "workgroup_session_id=7b97149fa98d76eb2b8ca9dafd209d64; path=/; HttpOnly"

Comment: Log a bug report against the runtime project at http://javafx-jira.kenai.com (make sure to include a simple executable test program, test site url, system environment, javafx version and any error messages or logs).