# JavaFX FXML: Blank WebView After Load

Tags: java, javafx, webview, sandbox, signing

When I try to load any html or urls using `webEngine.load();` my webView is just blank. From what I have read here "[JavaFX 2.2 WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479218/javafx-2-2-webview)" it seems like I will have to sign my application to let it run outside of sandbox mode.
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deploy_overview.htm#CEGJGHDA

Is that what is causing this problem?

I am using NetBeans 8.1, and under Project Settings I am running it as Standalone. I have been following these tutorials and each has gone well.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/get_start_apps.htm#JFXST804

Here are my three files.

**FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.media.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="481.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <children>
            <HBox layoutX="157.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="287.0">
               <children>
                  <Label text="TwitchAid">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="53.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="38.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Twitchaid-Logo.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <WebView fx:id="webView" prefHeight="405.0" prefWidth="600.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

**Java**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package twitchauthorize;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Dylan
 */
public class TwitchAuthorize extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLTwitchAuthorize.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);   
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        stage.setResizable(false);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**Controller.java**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package twitchauthorize;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

/**
 *
 * @author Dylan
 */
public class FXMLTwitchAuthorizeController {

    @FXML
    private WebView webView;

    @FXML
    private void initialize(){
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.load("http://www.google.com");
    }

}
```

Comment: If those who are downvoting my question could tell me why they are doing it I'd gladly use the information to improve my question so I don't get banned :)

Comment: I didn't down vote yet, but there is not enough information provided in your question to fully understand what you are asking.  How are you running your application?  If it is not a browser embedded application or webstart application, then it has full system privileges without signing the code.  As you can see from [packaging basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packaging.html#BABCIBAD), there are many ways to package and run applications and how you do that can effect application privileges.  If it were a privilege error, there would usually be a stacktrace.

Comment: If it is a browser embedded application, it would be kind of a weird application, as you would be embedding a web view for showing html inside a java application inside a web browser for showing html.  Also, support for browser embedded applications are [soon to be deprecated](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free) by Oracle and are already or will soon be [no longer be supported by the browser vendors](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/npapi_plugin_perspectives_and_the) either.

Comment: A couple of question down votes, won't get you banned, you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: @jewelsea - If this helps, I am using NetBeans 8.1, and under Project Settings I am running it as Standalone. There is no error being thrown so it may not be a privilege error.

Comment: @jewelsea I have been following these tutorials and each worked well.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/get_start_apps.htm#JFXST804

Comment: Your question is unrelated to the [JavaFX 2.2 WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479218/javafx-2-2-webview) question that you linked.   The linked question is specific to deployments in a browser or via webstart, neither of which is applicable to your deployment model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified a controller in your FXML, so the initialize method of the controller is never executed.

Add the following attribute definition to the VBox element that forms the root element of your FXML:

```
fx:controller="twitchauthorize.FXMLTwitchAuthorizeController"
```

Comment: I literally just found that out for myself by seeing my print statements not execute and then starting up a new empty project and searching for why my controller wasn't working. Thank you very much for the help @jewelsea. I've been on this problem since noon aha.